# Согласование числа с "или": "мне нужен/нужны нож или ножницы"?

Tags: грамматика, множественное-число, стилистика, согласование

Можно ли сказать

> Мне нужен/нужны нож или ножницы?

Вариант

> Мне нужны ножницы или нож

кажется лучше, поскольку глагол и согласуется с ближайшим словом, и стоит во множественном числе, но какое или какие из правил применяется или применяются в русском языке? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Использование твоего варианта будет правильней,

> Мне нужны ножницы или нож

но использование варианта ниже тоже не будет ошибкой.

> Мне нужен нож или ножницы

Comment: А почему правильней первый вариант? Какое есть правило на этот счет?

Comment: Если возникает необходимость согласования по роду, и род разный — множественное число ("Там стояли мальчик или девочка"). Если род одинаковый или согласование по роду не нужно — в единственном ("Там стоит мальчик или девочка"). Собственно, то же и к числу должно относиться, хотя явно не сказано (но "Там была сестра или девочки" явно не согласуется: у нас множественное число обычно работает как род). «Ножницы» по "роду" не согласуются ни с одним существительным единственного числа, поэтому при любом сказуемом, различающем число, придётся использовать множественное число.

Comment: По крайней мере, по нормам так. В речи бывает по-разному)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант `Мне нужны нож или ножницы` неправилен (хотя это довольно простительная ошибка), два других — вполне корректны.

Однако, при обратном построении фразы, скажем

```
— Кому следует передать всё это барахло?
— Про всё барахло не знаю, но нож или ножницы нужны мне.
```

множественное число должно употребляться всегда, когда упоминаемые предметы различаются по числам или родам: `нож или вилка нужны мне`, но `вилка или ложка нужна мне`.

Предупреждение: это лишь чувство носителя языка, я не специалист.

Answer (score -1):

Если нужны несколько предметов, то должно употребляться множественное число - *Мне нужны нож и вилка (ножницы)*.

В разговорной, особенно спонтанной, речи иногда используют вариант с единственным числом глагола, но нормативность подобного согласования крайне сомнительна.

Comment: В данном случае речь идёт об "или"; то есть, нужен один предмет.